Linux Debian 7 cluster /root directory (/) space needs reduction
I have a Linux cluster running Debian 7. Its root directory disk space has almost reached its capacity and needs immediate space reduction.
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  449G  352G   75G  83% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   6.4G  2.6M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/11abc561-375a-4d3d-bfb3-e066a983e369  449G  352G   75G  83% /

I looked for the solutions leading to various web links such as: Root drive disk space, Free up Linux system disk space.
However, all such links somehow carry drawbacks and warnings of data deletion or dysfunctionality of the cluster.
Could you please provide a one-time solution which does not perturb the system functionality during the root directory disk space reduction?
Thanks.

Please [edit] your question and tell us how you have set this up. What's your partitioning scheme? Are you using LVM?

Food for thought: Debian 7 received its last update 8 years ago. You may want to consider setting up a new machine at this point.

how is "83% full" the same as "almost reached its capacity"? Why do you expect a sudden appearance of 75 more Gigabyte

Boot from your install medium or any Live distribution. You'll corrupt your disk if you try to alter partition info while any partition is mounted. Use swapoff in the Live system to ensure NO disk partition is in use. I agree with @panki - upgrade; stay current.

As Panki Points out: It's time to upgrade.  Gather the requirements of the cluster server, and rebuild an almost identical copy using at least Debian 11.  That said if you choose not to upgrade, you cannot be using the server while resizing, as walter points out.  You'll need a tool like CloneZilla or GParted.  Even if this works, I'd be weary of a resize due to the HDD's age.

Thanks everyone. I will come back later after sorting out the issue with OS version upgradation then.

I have another Linux clusterr running Debian 11, it is actually a backup server (data from various linux HPCs are being backed up onto this server).
On one of the mounted LVs of this backupserver (/mnt/space1/backup), free disk space is <20%.
space1: Infortrend DS3016 disk array
Could you suggest ways to tackle the disk space around /mnt/space1/backup. Let me know if any other information needs to be furnished to facilitate the discussion.
